# macports mysql PID file error

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I have macports mysql 5, and I disabled the bin logs by commenting this line out:

```
log-bin=mysql-bin
```

Then I manually deleted the bin files. After I tried to restart my server I got:

```
 ERROR! MySQL manager or server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
...... ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your socket path: `grep socket /path/to/my.cnf`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on mac os x mountain lion after an os update.
I needed to remove the ACLs of the folders "/opt/local/var/run/mysql5" and "/opt/local/var/db/mysql5"

On OS X you can do this with the following commands in the named folders.

```
sudo chmod -R -N ./*
sudo chmod -N .
sudo chmod -N .turd_mysql5-server
```